# KML file without coordinates

Tags: kml

Is it possible to create a KML file without coordinates in it?  I have a list of addresses and I don't have the long/lat.  I'd like to create a KML file and have Google Earth geocode and determine the long/lat for each placemark.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

The geometry (e.g. Point, Polygon, etc.) in a KML Placemark is not required.

You can just have an [address](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#address) in your KML placemarks and Google Earth will automatically geodecode it for you if it can. Under the covers Google Earth will perform a lookup on that address and use the first match if any results are returned. Basically, the resolved address will be the same as if you entered an address via search panel in Google Earth or Google Maps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Placemark>
        <name>Google place</name>
        <address>1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA</address>
    </Placemark>
</kml>
```

After that if you save your KML then Google Earth will have inserted the coordinates for you into each Placemark.

```
<Point>
    <coordinates>-122.083954,37.421998,0</coordinates>
</Point>
```

Comment: Google Earth and My Maps no longer support this behaviour.

Comment: Google Earth Pro (Desktop version) still supports this behavior and creates a MultiGeometry from the address with a center Point and a LinearRing for an outline of the address.

Answer (score 0):

You can create KML file without coordinates when you have an address in your file. You can input the data from MS Excel for instance, if you are interested a batch operation. See the solution below:

http://www.mkrgeo-blog.com/input-a-multiple-address-list-in-google-maps-and-google-earth-the-quickest-way/

Then Google Earth will geocode your placemarks automatically when save it as a .kml file again.
It only works when you have no additional data in your excel column. If so, then you must import the Excel spreadsheet to the Google Earth directly, as per the explanation below:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298570/exporting-layer-from-google-my-maps-as-kml-has-no-geometries/332642#332642